# Display Entries in a calendar

Tags: entries, date, postdate, queries

I have a section for holding calendar entries stored by postDate in the CMS.
On the front end I want to basically display these in a calendar.

I have code which displays the calendar looping through each day of the month.
For each day it currently queries if there is any entries for this day.

Is there a better way to do it? - my current method had a query for each day?

Current code is:

```
<table class="cal">
  <thead class="hide-for-small">
    <tr>
      <th width="300">Sun</th>
      <th width="300">Mon</th>
      <th width="300">Tue</th>
      <th width="300">Wed</th>
      <th width="300">Thu</th>
      <th width="300">Fri</th>
      <th width="300">Sat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    {% set time = "now"|date("U") %}        
    {% set daysInMonth = time|date('t') %}
    {% set startDow = time|date('F 1\\s\\t Y')|date('w') %}
    {% set dow = startDow %}
    {% for day in range(1,daysInMonth) %}
        {% if loop.first and startDow != 0 %}
            <td colspan="{{ startDow }}"></td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>
            <div>
                <span class="day">{{ day }}</span>
                    {% set today=thisyear ~ "/" ~ thismonth ~ "/" ~ day %}

                    {% if (category is defined) and (category is not empty) %}
                    {% set params = { section: 'calendar', status: null, postDate:today|date('Y-m-d'), relatedTo: category } %}
                    {% else %}
                    {% set params = { section: 'calendar', status: null, postDate:today|date('Y-m-d') } %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% set entries = craft.entries(params)%}
                    {% if entries|length %}
                <div>
                    {% for entry in entries %}
                    <span class="event green">{{ entry.title }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
        </td>
        {% if loop.last and dow != 6 %}
            <td colspan="{{ 6 - dow }}">&nbsp;</td>
        {% endif %}
        {% if dow == 6 %}
            {% set dow = 0 %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {% else %}
            {% set dow = dow + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi mmc501. Did you ever finish the code with the answer from Stephen Lewis? I am looking to output a mini calendar with prev/next month etc. any help appreciated!

Comment: @outline4 yes I finished it and have a working version. Can get it when I return from holidays next week

Comment: That'd be great!

Comment: are you back from your holidays? cheers stefan

Comment: Yes - I will post it as an additional answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should be a good starting point, at the very least.

```
{# Determine the number of days in the month #}
{% set daysInMonth = "now"|date("t") %}

{# Determine the date range spanning the month #}
{% set firstDayOfMonth = "now"|date("Y-m-01") %}
{% set firstDayOfNextMonth = "now"|date_modify("first day of next month")|date("Y-m-01") %}
{% set postDateParam = "and, >= " ~ firstDayOfMonth ~ ", < " ~ firstDayOfNextMonth %}

{# Create our parameters object #}
{% if (category is defined) and (category is not empty) %}
    {% set params = {section: 'calendar', postDate: postDateParam, status: null, order: 'postDate', relatedTo: category} %}
{% else %}
    {% set params = {section: 'calendar', postDate: postDateParam, status: null, order: 'postDate'} %}
{% endif %}

{# Retrieve all of the events for the month, and group them by day #}
{% set groupedEvents = craft.entries(params)|group('postDate|date("Y-m-d")') %}

{# Set a shortcut for the YYYY-MM portion of the current month #}
{% set yearMonth = "now"|date("Y-m") %}

{# Loop through all of the days in the month #}
{% for day in range(1, daysInMonth) %}
    {% set formattedDay = "%02d"|format(day) %}
    {% set dayOfMonth = yearMonth ~ "-" ~ formattedDay) %}

    {# If the current day is a key in our groupedEvents array, we have events #}
    {% if dayOfMonth in groupedEvents|keys %}
        <span class="day">{{ dayOfMonth }}</span>

        <div>
            {% for event in groupedEvents[dayOfMonth] %}
                <span class="event green">{{ event.title }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As I said, I haven't tested the above code, but the basic principle works (I've used it for grouping people by surname, and so forth).

Let me know if anything is unclear, I realise it's quite the chunk of Twig.

Stephen

Comment: Stephen, you need to change the date filtering to get all entries within a datetime range. See [this Q/A](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1821/125) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - works well - needed to change the date filtering as carlcs said.
But I'm not getting all events pulled in - missing one on the 1st of the month. will add code below

Comment: @mmc501 when did you add your events to Craft? There were a couple of timezone related bugs which got fixed with Craft version [2.0.2528](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2528), [1.2.2375](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2375) and [0.9.2235](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2235). I'd try to edit the date of that missing event on the 1st of the month with the timepicker (change it to the 2nd → save, change it back to the 1st → save).

Comment: Within the last couple of weeks.
Tried editing the date of the event - discovered that if it's the 1st - 9th of the month it will not display but from the 10th on it will - must be something to do with single figure date - will have a play with it not to see if can resolve.

Comment: @mmc501 I've updated my example to format the day as a two-digit number (take a look at the first line of the `for day in range` loop).

Comment: @carlcs Thanks for fixing the date range query.

Comment: Excellent! - working great now! Much better than my original solution with a query for every day.

Comment: @mmc501 Nice one. We got there eventually.

Comment: Was a pleasure to contribute to this nice Q/A, @stephen. I'm sure that I will use this code snippet at some point! One question (and please correct it with the code), what's the right or most common way to say it: timeframe, date range, interval?

Comment: @carlcs In this case I'd be inclined to go with timeframe or date range. Interval suggests a regular, repeating period of time.

Comment: @carlcs Having said that, I've just updated the example to use the rather more prosaic (but less potentially confusing) `postDateParam`.

Comment: @mmc501 didn't you miss events that are on the last calendar day? See my edit to the code..

Comment: Cheers @carlcs - hadn't tested an entry on the last day of the month - updated to your edit now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just an update to show final current version of code for calendar - re stefan comment.

```
  {% if year is defined and month is defined %}
      {% set time = (year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ "01") %}
      {% set catslug = craft.app.request.segment(2) %}
      {% if catslug != 'all' %}
        {% set category = craft.categories.group('eventFilters').slug(catslug) %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if time is not defined%} 
      {% set time = "now" %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if catslug is not defined or catslug is empty%} 
      {% set catslug = "all" %}
  {% endif %}

  {% set thisyear = time|date("Y") %}
  {% set thismonth = time|date("m") %}
  {% set prevyear = time|date_modify("-1 month")|date("Y") %}
  {% set prevmonth = time|date_modify("-1 month")|date("m") %}
  {% set nextyear = time|date_modify("+1 month")|date("Y") %}
  {% set nextmonth = time|date_modify("+1 month")|date("m") %}



  <!-- CONTENT -->

  <div class="row calhead text-center align-items-center py-2 mb-3">
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="calchange calleft" href="#" data-slug="{{ catslug }}" data-month="{{ prevmonth }}" data-year="{{ prevyear }}">
          <span class="fa-stack ">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>  
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col"><div class="caldate">{{ time|date("F")}} {{ time|date("Y")}}</div></div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <a class="calchange calright" href="#" data-slug="{{ catslug }}" data-month="{{ nextmonth }}" data-year="{{ nextyear }}">
          <span class="fa-stack ">
            <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
          </span>          
        </a>
      </div>

  </div>


  <div class="dayscontainer clearfix pb-3">
    <div class="row text-center dayhead mb-3">
      <div class="col">M</div>
      <div class="col">T</div>
      <div class="col">W</div>    
      <div class="col">T</div>
      <div class="col">F</div>
      <div class="col">S</div>
      <div class="col">S</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center mb-1">
        {% if year is defined and month is defined %}
            {% set time = (year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ "01") %}
        {% endif%}
        {% if time is not defined%} 
            {% set time = "now" %}
        {% endif %}

            {% set daysInMonth = time|date('t') %}
            {% set startDow = time|date('F 1\\s\\t Y')|date('w') %}
            {% set dow = startDow %}



        {% set yearMonth = time|date("Y-m") %}                 

        {% set startdate=(yearMonth ~ "-" ~ "01") %}
        {% set enddate=(yearMonth ~ "-" ~ daysInMonth) %}
         {# Create our parameters object #}

        {% if (category is defined) and (category is not empty) %}
        {% set params = { section: 'events', orderBy: 'eventDate', relatedTo: category } %}
        {% else %}
        {% set params = { section: 'events', orderBy: 'eventDate' } %}
        {% endif %}          
        {% set j = 0 %}
        {# Retrieve all of the events for the month, and group them by day #}
        {% set groupedEvents = craft.entries(params).eventDate(['and', '>= ' ~ startdate|date('Y-m-d'), '<= ' ~ enddate|date('Y-m-d')]).all() | group('eventDate|date("Y-m-d")') %}



          {% for day in range(1,daysInMonth) %}
            {% set formattedDay = "%02d"|format(day) %}
            {% set dayOfMonth = yearMonth ~ "-" ~ formattedDay %}       

            {# set dayOfMonth = "#{yearMonth}-#{day}" #}
            {% if startDow == 0 %}
              {% set startDow = 7 %}
            {% endif %}


              {% if loop.first and startDow > 1 %}
                {% for i in range(1,startDow-1) %}
                  {% set j = j + 1 %}
                  <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
                {% endfor %}              

              {% endif %}
              {% set j = j + 1 %}

              {% if j == 8 %}

                </div>
                <div class="row text-center mb-1">
                {% set j = 1 %}
              {% endif %}

              <div class="col">

                {# If the current day is a key in our groupedEvents array, we have events #}
                {% if dayOfMonth in groupedEvents|keys %}
                  {% set ccontent %}
                      {% for entry in groupedEvents[dayOfMonth] %}
                      {% set category = entry.eventFilter.one() %}

                      <span class="event"><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  {% endset %}

                  <span class="day"><a role="button" class="pop daylink" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click hover focus" data-html="true" title="Events" data-content='{{ ccontent }}'>{{ day }}</a></span>
                {% else %}
                  <span class="day">{{ day }}</span>  

                {% endif %}
              </div>

              {% if loop.last and j < 7 %}
                {% for i in range(1,7 -j) %}
                  <div class="col">&nbsp;</div>
                {% endfor %}              

              {% endif %}              

          {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give this a try as soon as possible!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this @mmc501
I have adapted the code to work the wonderful [sprig](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/sprig) plugin.

```
{% set time = time ?? "now" %}

<div class="grid text-center">
    <div class="col">
        <button sprig s-vars="time: '{{time|date_modify('-1 month')|date()}}'">Prev</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="caldate">{{ time|date("F")}} {{ time|date("Y")}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button sprig s-vars="time: '{{time|date_modify('+1 month')|date()}}'">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dayscontainer">

    <div class="grid text-center">
        <div class="col">M</div>
        <div class="col">T</div>
        <div class="col">W</div>
        <div class="col">T</div>
        <div class="col">F</div>
        <div class="col">S</div>
        <div class="col">S</div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid text-center">
        {% set daysInMonth = time|date('t') %}
        {% set startDow = time|date('F 1\\s\\t Y')|date('w') %}

        {% set yearMonth = time|date("Y-m") %}                 

        {% set startdate=(yearMonth ~ "-" ~ "01") %}
        {% set enddate=(yearMonth ~ "-" ~ daysInMonth) %}

        {% set params = { section: 'externalEvents', orderBy: 'startDateTime' } %}

        {% set j = 0 %}

        {% set groupedEvents = craft.entries(params).startDateTime(['and', '>= ' ~ startdate|date('Y-m-d'), '<= ' ~ enddate|date('Y-m-d')]).all()|group('startDateTime|date("Y-m-d")') %}

        {% for day in range(1,daysInMonth) %}
            {% set formattedDay = "%02d"|format(day) %}
            {% set dayOfMonth = yearMonth ~ "-" ~ formattedDay %}       

            {% if startDow == 0 %}
                {% set startDow = 7 %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if loop.first and startDow > 1 %}
                {% for i in range(1,startDow-1) %}
                    {% set j = j + 1 %}
                    <div class="col"></div>
                {% endfor %}              
            {% endif %}

            {% set j = j + 1 %}

            {% if j == 8 %}
                </div>
                <div class="grid text-center">
                {% set j = 1 %}
            {% endif %}

            <div class="col">
                {% if dayOfMonth in groupedEvents|keys %}
                    {% for entry in groupedEvents[dayOfMonth] %}
                        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {{ day }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ day }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            {% if loop.last and j < 7 %}
                {% for i in range(1,7 -j) %}
                    <div class="col"></div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```