# Calendar archives architecture

Tags: entries, datetime, queries, calendar

I created a section on a site that shows a two-month calendar. The calendar has links to entries based on a release date. The release dates are created using a date/time filed. (Dates are different than the entry release date)

I'm very happy with the results so far. I took some ideas from [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1849/979) and a little [flexbox magic](http://turpialcreative.com/notebook/making-a-responsive-calendar-for-dynamic-dates-using-flexbox). Everything is working great for the current/next month to show.

What I'm looking for is some ideas on how to display past dates. I want to create an "archive" section of the calendar where people can navigate to a month in the past to see the events that took place in that specific month.

Should I create a category group called "months" and then manually add months as they pass, changing the DateTime object?

Any ideas on the best way to display months in the past would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your past entries by month as explained [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6549/6991). Than it's just a matter of displaying them they way you want to.